# oci: Using an array instead of multiple oci_bind_by_name

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm looking for a way to bind my prepared requests in oci like in PDO :

```
// Using PDO :
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt = $dbh->execute($params);
```

With for example

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?";
$params = array('foo', 'toto');
```

My issue is that i want to use Oracle in one of my projects and i need to modify all my class DataBaseAccessor, which is based on the `$sql` and `$params`. If there's any way for me to not modify all my code, it could be cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PDO_OCI`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php). [`OCI8`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) functions only support named variable binding for reasons unknown to me.

---

***Edit:***

Here's an example:

```
$db = new PDO('oci:dbname=hostname/database;charset=AL32UTF8', 'usr', 'pwd');

$stmt = $db->prepare('select 1, 2, 3, ? as "test" from dual');
$stmt->execute(['x']);

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [test] => x
        )
)
```

This assumes you want to access the fields by name (associative array) in which case it's important to add a field alias ("test" in the example above) or the field name will be pseudo-randomly assigned.  For example:

```
[:PDO1] => 'x'
```

Comment: @FunkySayu Any feedback on this?

Comment: I literally forgot about marking this question. I did it another way (a... really messy and bad way), and I shall follow your answer. Thank you for trying.